# Is the line connecting the circumcircle and Excenter is perpendicular to DE?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I recently found a lemma that

$\textbf{Lemma:}$ the line connecting  the circumcenter and A-excenter is perpendicular to the line formed by intersections of  the B-angle bisector and C-angle bisector with their respective opposite sides.
I tried much but couldn't find a proof.
Can anyone please help me with the proof?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ and $Q$ be the intersections of the radical axis of the circumcircle and the $A$-excircle with $AB$ and $AC$, respectively. We have
$$PB\cdot PA=\operatorname{Pow}_{(O)}(P)=\operatorname{Pow}_{(O_a)}(P)=PF^2,$$
where $F$ is the tangency point of the $A$-excircle to $AB$. Thus, letting $a=BC$, etc. and $s=\frac{AB+BC+CA}{2}=AF$,
$$PA(PA-c)=(s-PA)^2\implies PA=\frac{s^2}{2s-c}=\frac{s^2}{a+b}.$$
Similarly $QA=\frac{s^2}{a+c}$. However, we have by the angle bisector theorem that
$$AB_b=\frac{bc}{a+c},\ AC_b=\frac{bc}{a+b},$$
so $\triangle AB_bC_b\sim\triangle AQP$. This means $B_bC_b || PQ$, but $PQ\perp OO_a$, so we are done.